# Time Complexity: Big-O

Tags: time-complexity

What is the time complexity of this loop?

```
k=1
for(j=0;j<=n;j+=k)
    k++;
```

Is it $O(n)$ as we are increasing $j$ linearly?

Comment: **Hint:** j is actually the Gaussian sum.

Comment: Cant understand, if  you can provide an explanation it will be of much help, even I have no answer manual to confirm, nor its an assignment, if I left this without understanding, it will remain like this for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the values of $j$ at the end of each iteration:
$$
1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36,45,55,\ldots
$$
More generally, after $t$ iterations, $j = 1 + \cdots + t = \binom{t+1}{2} = \Theta(t^2)$. Therefore the loop halts after $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$ iterations.

Comment: Thanks a ton .. :)